# Breadcrumb splits my node title

Tags: breadcrumbs

If I have a title that is longer than one line, then the bread crumb trail in the middle of it.

Example:
http://www.energyjustice.net/node/1948

I want the bread crumb trail to either come before or after the title.

I'm using Drupal 7.19

Comment: You should considering not having so long titles? It's not recommended anyhow.

Comment: I agree, but I'm not writing them =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, get rid of this:

```
#wrapper #container .breadcrumb {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 35px;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

The absolute positioning is where you're falling over.  Unless an element's parent is explicitly using `position: relative`, `position: absolute` is nothing but a pain in the backside.

After that, you just need to add a clearfix. If you Google clearfix, then you'll get a slew of results, however here is my favourite:

If you only want to support IE8+:

```
.breadcrumb:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

If you want to support IE6/7

```
.breadcrumb:before,
.breadcrumb:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
} 
.breadcrumb:after {
    clear: both;
}
.breadcrumb {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
```

This'll put the breadcrumbs above your page title, as per your request :)

Comment: Just out of interest, would the downvoter care to explain the downvote?  Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this style to your CSS file

```
#squeeze .right-corner .left-corner .breadcrumb {
  position: static;
}
```

This will position your breadcrumbs div according to the normal flow of the page.